# How can I make audio play for duration of a countdown timer in React?

Tags: reactjs, audio, timer, mp3, countdown

I'm trying to play an audio file for the duration of the timer. The way I current have this structured, the audio file plays for 1 sec and cuts off. How can I make the audio play for the full length of the timer?

I'm using the Countdown Circle Timer project: https://github.com/vydimitrov/react-countdown-circle-timer

I have `renderTime` structured so that a start button appears at page load and again at the end of the duration of the timer. Since the `play()` function is coupled with the "start" button, the audio only plays for as long as the button is rendered (1 second).

Here's a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-heisenberg-8ejug

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { CountdownCircleTimer } from "react-countdown-circle-timer";

class Timer extends Component {
    state = {
        isPlaying: false,
        durationSeconds: 31,
        colors: [["#dadfe0", 1]]
    };

    startTimer = () => {
        this.setState({
            isPlaying: true,
            colors: [["#ee5253", 0.33], ["#feca57", 0.33], ["#1abc9c"]]
        });
        const audioEl = document.getElementsByClassName("audio-element")[0]
        audioEl.play();
    };

    resetTimer = () => {
        if (this.state.isPlaying === false) {
            this.setState({
                isPlaying: true,
                colors: [["#ee5253", 0.33], ["#feca57", 0.33], ["#1abc9c"]]
            });
        }
    };

    render() {
        const isPlaying = this.state.isPlaying;

        const durationSeconds = this.state.durationSeconds;

        const colors = this.state.colors;

        const renderTime = value => {
            if (value === 0) {
                return (
                    <div className="timer">
                    <button className="btn-white" onClick={this.resetTimer}>Start</button>
                    </div>
                )
            }

            if (value === 31) {
                return (
                    <div className="timer">
                    <button className="btn-white" onClick={this.startTimer}>Start</button>
                    <audio className="audio-element">
                        <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-demos/DDR_assets/Sevish_-__nbsp_.mp3"></source>
                    </audio>
                    </div>
                )
            }

            if (value <= 30) {
                return (
                    <div className="timer">
                        <div className="value">{value}</div>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        };

        return (
            <CountdownCircleTimer
            isPlaying={isPlaying}
            size={240}
            durationSeconds={durationSeconds}
            colors={colors}
            trailColor={"#dadfe0"}
            strokeWidth={20}
            renderTime={renderTime}
            onComplete={() => [false]}
            />
        );
    }
}

    export default Timer;
```

Thanks for any advice you can give!

Comment: I believe its because you either lose the reference to `audio-element` or because your `const audioEl` goes out of scope, I might be wrong though. Can you please make this into a sandbox ?

Comment: Thanks @LoXatoR! I added a link to a sandbox in the question above.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I added the audio element to app.js and then added a pause function to the renderTime const to stop the audio on timer completion.

Comment: Awesome! Hope I was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, the `audio` element was being removed. After adding it to this code block

```
  if (value <= 30) {
        return (
          <div className="timer">
            <div className="value">{value}</div>
            <audio className="audio-element">
              <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-demos/DDR_assets/Sevish_-__nbsp_.mp3" />
            </audio>
          </div>
        );
      }
```

You can see it plays till the specified time.

Code sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-cookies-q03ro